# my android phone stopped suddenly

Tags: android, android-debug

I am developing an android app and was trying this app on my phone, my phone has several problems in it so it's not quit good... and I'm just using it for development but was trying my app on it and the app started and suddenly the screen freezed and the phone shut down and I can't turn it on again so I need to know can an app do that if it contains bad code or... because I ran the app on an emulator and it worked exactly as I needed with no errors... and now my pc is not recognising the usb anymore... so anyone had this problem before? thank you.

here's the logcat:

```
10-10 13:35:39.990: E/arm-runtime(492): /mnt/sdcard is not mounted.
10-10 13:35:39.990: E/arm-runtime(492): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
10-10 13:35:40.990: E/pppd(501): In file /etc/ppp/peers/gprs: unrecognized option '/dev/ttyUSB0'
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/ServiceManager(485): add_service('bsttest',0x2) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/control/control.c:902:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL AndroidOut
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/mixer/simple_none.c:1546:(simple_add1) helem (MIXER,'PCM Capture Volume',0,0,1) appears twice or more
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/AudioHardwareALSA(495): Unable to load mixer elements: Invalid argument
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/control/control.c:902:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL AndroidIn
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/mixer/simple_none.c:1546:(simple_add1) helem (MIXER,'PCM Capture Volume',0,0,1) appears twice or more
10-10 13:35:48.460: E/AudioHardwareALSA(495): Unable to load mixer elements: Invalid argument
10-10 13:35:48.810: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker_normal
10-10 13:35:48.810: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker
10-10 13:35:48.810: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback
10-10 13:35:48.850: E/ALSALib(495): external/alsa-lib/src/confmisc.c:136:(snd_config_get_bool) Invalid type for nonblock
10-10 13:36:00.970: E/Zygote(491): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
10-10 13:36:00.970: E/Zygote(492): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
10-10 13:36:07.820: E/Zygote(492): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
10-10 13:36:10.120: E/Zygote(491): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): usbOnlinePath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryStatusPath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryHealthPath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryPresentPath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryCapacityPath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryVoltagePath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryTemperaturePath not found
10-10 13:36:10.320: E/BatteryService(521): batteryTechnologyPath not found
10-10 13:36:10.350: E/SurfaceFlinger(521): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
10-10 13:36:11.370: E/HdIpc(521): Connect failed err = -1 errno = 110 (ETIMEDOUT). Timeout log will be logged only once per process
10-10 13:36:11.370: E/PGA(521): Failed to connect to host, err = -1, retrying... This will be logged only once per process to avoid flooding the logs.
```

Comment: I have a feeling that you softbricked your phone.

Comment: but I told you my software worked just fine on the emulator... plus my phone's led is still on but when I booted it it got me a screen with black lines on it and it shut down...

Comment: post your logcat trace

Comment: this is the logcat but I just outputted the errors...

Comment: ok tried the app on my brother's phone worked perfectly so I don't know what the problem is... I think it's my phone.. or what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem, mine did it this morning as well.  It happens when the battery runs out.

Answer (score 0):

let it off for an hour and then pressed the power button with the volume up button and it turned on although I pressed these buttons before and got no result I didn't know what the problem was but it's working again...